# Smartsheet data in Excel via Power Query

Tags: json, excel, powerquery, smartsheet-api

The API output from Smartsheet returns rows and columns as separate objects,that are independent of each other.
This results in separate records for the columns(A list of field names) and another set of records for the rows(records with a single field of values from various fields)

Is there a way to return a single list of JSON (with rows and columns resulting in a single list of records)?

This is the code I'm using in the Query Editor that returns separate Rows and Columns

```
= Web.Contents(
    "https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/[SHEET_ID]",
    [
        Headers = 
        [
            #"Authorization" = "Bearer YOUR_API_TOKEN"
        ]
    ]
)
```

Comment: On a related note, let me also point out that figuring out how to connect to an authenticated REST API service from PQ was non-trivial.  Here is how I got it to work:

(1) in PQ editor I hardcoded the auth header + API token:
= Web.Contents(“https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/4693183612381060”, 
[ Headers=[#“Authorization” = “Bearer YOUR_API_TOKEN”]])

(2) when prompted to enter credentials, I chose Anonymous instead of Web API, as someone suggested in the comments here http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/getting-data-into-power-query-with-the-twitter-search-api-how-to-hack-pq-to-use-oauth/

Comment: Ivan, Can you provide an example of what you would like the output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

I used the sample data on their site to come up with this set of transformations:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("D:\testdata\foo.json")),
    ColumnIds = List.Transform(Source[columns], each Text.From([id])),
    ColumnNames = List.Transform(Source[columns], each [title]),
    Table = Table.FromList(Source[rows], Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    Expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Table, "Column1", {"rowNumber", "cells"}, {"rowNumber", "cells"}),
    Mapped = Table.TransformColumns(Expanded, {"cells",
        each Record.Combine(List.Transform(_, each Record.AddField([], Text.From([columnId]), [value])))}),
    Result = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Mapped, "cells", ColumnIds, ColumnNames)
in
    Result
```

Answer (score 0):

The Curt Hagenlocher's answer was exactly I was looking for

I did some changes to get rowIDs and solve some issue if the sheet or some column is empty

```
    let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\0\0\0\0\test.json")),
    ColumnIds = List.Transform(Source[columns], each Text.From([id])),
    ColumnNames = List.Transform(Source[columns], each [title]),
    Table = Table.FromList(Source[rows], Splitter.SplitByNothing(), 1, {"id", "rowNumber", "cells"}, ExtraValues.Error),
    Expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Table, "Column1", {"id", "rowNumber", "cells"}, {"id", "rowNumber", "cells"}),
    Mapped = Table.TransformColumns(Expanded, {"cells",
        each Record.Combine(List.Transform(_, each Record.AddField([], Text.From([columnId]), try [value] otherwise null)))}),
    Result = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Mapped, "cells", ColumnIds, ColumnNames),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Result,{{"id", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```